# Get error to build my project in Vite - Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment

Tags: typescript, vite

I try to build my project in vite,

my project - https://github.com/yakovcohen4/starbucks-openlayers

I run `npm run dev` and all work.

but when I run to build it I get an error.

error message:
`Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2019", "firefox78", "safari13.1")`

I try to fetch a data and think here is the problem
link (line 22+23) -  https://github.com/yakovcohen4/starbucks-openlayers/blob/main/starbucks-project/src/main.ts

`const shopsData = await fetchStarbucksShops();`

If anyone encounters this curse I would be happy to help

Answer (score 35):

Top-level-await is a new es feature which wouldn't run in old browsers. If you believe your users use relatively new versions and can handle top-level-await, you can set up vite.config like this:

```
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    target: 'esnext' //browsers can handle the latest ES features
  }
})
```

or

```
export default defineConfig({
  esbuild: {
    supported: {
      'top-level-await': true //browsers can handle top-level-await features
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: Both configurations miss a closing bracket (`)`) at the end.

Comment: I prefer setting `supported` features so that I can see other potential errors if they arise in future. `esnext` [is not a fixed version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521178/what-is-esnext). See my answer for how to target a specific dependency too.

Comment: Can someone help me understand why this worked please? I already had lib: { formats: 'esnext' }, but adding this option was the only thing that made it work. Is it because it asserts to esbuild to just use top level await, and the formats option does not?

Answer (score 13):

For those who experience the same issue in the both dev and build commands, add the following

```js
// vite.config.js
optimizeDeps: {
   esbuildOptions: {
     target: 'esnext'
   }
 },
 build: {
   target: 'esnext'
 }
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me. "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.2","vite": "^5.0.11"

Comment: Adding `esbuildOptions: { target: 'esnext' }` to `optimizeDeps` was the fix for me. Tried other variations of `build` and `esbuild` target settings but it was this one that fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

["Top-level await" is am ES2022 feature](https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/11/25/ecmascript-top-level-await/). Check to see which browsers are supported using [CanIUse.com - await: top-level](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_await_top_level).

**Option 1** - If `top-level await` is in the list of your supported browsers, then you can safely ignore this error with the Vite config below. This is my prefered method of disabling the build error as it only ignores a specific ES feature and doesn't hide errors from other potential breaking changes.

Set up your `vite.config.js` or `vite.config.ts` like this if the error is coming from your source code:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  esbuild: {
    supported: {
      'top-level-await': true
    },
  },
});
```

Set up your `vite.config.js` or `vite.config.ts` like this if the error is coming from a specific dependency, for instance `pdfjs-dist` (removing the dependency name will apply the rule to all dependencies):

```js
export default defineConfig({
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ["pdfjs-dist"], // optionally specify dependency name
    esbuildOptions: {
      supported: {
        "top-level-await": true
      },
    },
  },
});
```

**Option 2** - You can use a Vite plugin to remove the top level await. An example would be [vite-plugin-top-level-await](https://github.com/Menci/vite-plugin-top-level-await). The downside with this option is that you are adding yet another dependency to your project and it will also affect your production code. Bugs may be more difficult to trace as you have a more unique configuration.

Answer (score 3):

First, check this;
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6985.
If you can't find an answer try this to create a big fat async function that executes itself to decrease the level of your `await`;

```
    (async () => {
    export const shopsData: shopType[] = await fetchStarbucksShops();
    export const countryGeoData: countryGeoDataType = await fetchGeoJsonCountry();
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
     })();
```

It might not work.
You should avoid top-level await somehow, whether use `await` inside the `async` function, or use `.then()`

Comment: Thank you very much, in the end, I saw this repo and it helps me ...
(thank you for your answer)