# How do I use `import` for npm modules in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

My JavaScript Firebase Cloud Functions are running with npm modules imported with `require`. Now I want to use npm modules that are installed with `import`, not `require`. The Firebase Emulators throw this error:

```bash
 SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

The Node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-expressions) says:

> **`import` statements**
>
> An `import` statement can reference an ES module or a
> CommonJS module. `import` statements are permitted only in ES modules,
> but dynamic `import()` expressions are supported in CommonJS for loading
> ES modules.
>
> When importing CommonJS modules, the `module.exports` object is provided
> as the default export. Named exports may be available, provided by
> static analysis as a convenience for better ecosystem compatibility.
>
> **require**
>
> The CommonJS module `require` always treats the files it
> references as CommonJS.
>
> Using `require` to load an ES module is not supported because ES modules
> have asynchronous execution. Instead, use `import()` to load an ES
> module from a CommonJS module.

If I understand this correctly, Node modules can either be `ES` or `CommonJS`, that `import` handles both types, and `require` handles only `CommonJS`.

This documentation also suggests that my Cloud Function also needs to be an ES module to use `import`. Should the error message say:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside an **ES** module

That seems to be the problem: my Cloud Functions aren't in an ES module. How do I make an ES module for my Cloud Functions?

**Reproduce error**

Here's how to reproduce the error. Make a new directory and install Firebase, following the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started):

```bash
npm install -g firebase-tools
firebase init
```

Select `Emulators`.

Select `Create a new project`.

Select `Functions Emulator` and `Firestore Emulator`.

**Emulators Setup**

Accept the default ports. Download the emulators.

**Functions Setup**

Select `TypeScript`. Don't use ESLint. Install dependencies.

**Emulate execution of your functions**

```bash
firebase emulators:start
```

Here's the default `index.ts`.

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

// // Start writing Firebase Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

I also tried the module provided in the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/modules.html) on modules:

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export default function helloWorld() {
    console.log("Hello, world!");
  }
```

**Fix path to index.ts**

The first bug in `functions/package.json` is:

```
functions/lib/index.js does not exist, can't deploy Cloud Functions
```

Fix this by opening `functions/package.json` and changing

```js
"main": "lib/index.js",
```

to

```js
"main": "src/index.ts",
```

**Module error**

The next error is

```
Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

This is where I'm stuck. This seems to be saying that my Firebase Cloud Functions are not in an ES Module.

**package.json**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module) said to put `"type": "module",` in `functions/package.json`:

```js
{
    "name": "functions",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc",
        "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
        "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
        "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
        "start": "npm run shell",
        "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
        "logs": "firebase functions:log"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "16"
    },
    "main": "src/index.ts",
    "dependencies": {
        "firebase-admin": "^11.2.0",
        "firebase-functions": "^4.0.1",
        "got": "^12.5.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^4.7.4"
    },
    "private": true
}
```

That doesn't fix the error.

**tsconfig.json**

I opened `tsconfig.json` and changed `"module": "CommonJS",` to `"module": "ESNext",` and I changed `"target": "es2017"` to `"target": "ESNext"`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521178/what-is-esnext) explains what `ESNext` is.

The emulator continued to throw the error. Here's my `tsconfig.json` file:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESNext"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

**Recommended tsconfig.json**

The [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#handbook-content) recommends this `tsconfig.json`:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Recommended"
}
```

That throws the same error.

**Misconfiguration**

There's clearly more than one misconfiguration in the default `package.json` and `tsconfig.json`. If someone can tell me how to configure these correctly I'll do a pull request to `firebase-tools`.

I'm using Node 18.1.0. Firebase recommends Node 16.

Firebase Cloud Functions documentation on [handling dependencies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies) says to use `require` with JavaScript cloud functions and `import` with TypeScript cloud functions.

> Use the Node.js `require()` function to load any Node.js module you
> have installed. You can also use the `require()` function to import
> local files you deploy alongside your function.
>
> If you are writing functions in TypeScript, use the `import` statement
> in the same way to load any Node.js module you have installed.

That doesn't make sense if the Node.js documentation is correct. `require()` can't load any Node module, it only handles `CommonJS` modules. The paragraph about TypeScript seems to say that you can't use `import` with JavaScript Cloud Functions.

**ts-node**

Would [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) help?

Comment: When initializing Cloud Functions, had you selected Typescript? Firebase supports using ES6 syntax with TS only.